# Mouser cursor dissapears when moved to the right side of the screen

Tags: mouse, cursor

When i start my system the mouse cursor works as it should but whenever i move it to the right of the screen and a little bit more it disappears and i can see that it does show that is still active i cannot see it. It is the same issue on 17.04 through 18.04 and two different machines. One with 3 monitors and one with a single 4k tv. Any idea about this behaviour?

Comment: If you are talking about the behaviour shown in [this picture](https://imgur.com/a/8qKACLA) then it's quite normal. If I move my mouse to the right, then I can see only the leftmost pixels of the mouse cursor.